# How to use Doctrine entities as Value Objects in zend_amf?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, entity, zend-amf, value-objects

I use Doctrine in Zend framework and I would like to use existing Entity classes as Value Object.

The main obstacle I can see is how to deal with mappings. 
I don't want to lose information about associations.

Does anyone has some experience with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mappers into the models folder like without Doctrine, but you are use a Entity.

Comment: But how to deal with associations to other objects? Eg. `OneToMany` or `ManyToOne` ...